# How could I remove some entire object from an array inside another array when it has some property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need a function to delete some entire object inside an array:

```
let selectedItem = { LinkID: 1 };

let sindecs = [
  {
    estado: { id: 2, siga: "AL", nome: "Alagoas" },
    link: [
      { LinkID: 1, Link: "link1", Active: false },
      { LinkID: 2, Link: "link 2", Active: false }
    ],
    SindecID: 3
  },
  {
    estado: { id: 19, siga: "RJ", nome: "Rio de Janeiro" },
    link: [{ LinkID: 3, Link: "rio", Active: false }],
    SindecID: 4
  }
];
```

function removeLinkObj(sindecs, selectedItem){

```
// I need to fill here with a function to remove the selectedItem that match with === sindecs.link.LinkID
```

}

removeLinkObj(sindecs, selectedItem)

The result should be:

```
let sindecs = [
  {
    estado: { id: 2, siga: "AL", nome: "Alagoas" },
    link: [
    //REMOVED LINE
      { LinkID: 2, Link: "link 2", Active: false }
    ],
    SindecID: 3
  },
  {
    estado: { id: 19, siga: "RJ", nome: "Rio de Janeiro" },
    link: [{ LinkID: 3, Link: "rio", Active: false }],
    SindecID: 4
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeLinkObj(sindecs, selectedItem){

   return sindecs.map((row) => {

        row.link = row.link.filter(item => item.LinkID !== selectedItem.LinkID);
        return row;


   });

}
```

Comment: Thank you broo ! I test your code, I change the LinkId to LinkID and then it's work very well ! Thank you so much !

Comment: great. happy coding.